# Cocoapods header paths for vendor frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6, cocoapods

I've specified cocoa touch framework on iOS 8.1 as dependency on pod spec file:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyOwnFramework.framework'
```

Running the pod installs it, however the configuration files are not amended properly. I use the same local pod to pull some open source code that contains only headers and implementation files and the header files are stored correctly in `/Headers/Public` folder and it's path is added to my project configuration file.
However the header files from the framework are not added and path for them is also not created.

I also tried with `spec.header_dir = 'MyProject'`, but it didn't do any difference.

Half baked solution is to add them in additional configuration file, but I wonder if handling header files for frameworks could be done in a same way as it works with other types of dependencies, to be more in line with it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a problem. It's actually s.source_files that solves this. Not very self explanatory, especially if we consider there are properties like s`pec.header_dir` :)

```
s.source_files = 'Path_to_public_headers/*.h'
```

This one solves it.